# Sails skipper fails silently

Tags: sails.js, skipper

Using the code copied and pasted from the [docs](https://github.com/balderdashy/skipper/), the upload is not raising any errors (as is evidenced by the fact that if there was an error, it would return an HTTP status of 500 along with the error message).

```
req.file('avatar').upload(function (err, uploadedFiles) {
    if (err) return res.send(500, err);
    return res.json({
        message: uploadedFiles.length + ' file(s) uploaded successfully!',
        files: uploadedFiles
    });
});
```

However, `uploadedFiles` ends up with a length of 0.

I'm using the local disk adapter.

Any guesses on what could be going wrong?

Comment: Can you provide client-side code also?

Comment: @Glen actually, I am guessing that the problem is from the client-side. It is a [dropzone](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) element, built into a React component. I am inquiring in a separate question about the issues regarding the dropzone element [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44039671/dropzone-sending-a-request-with-application-x-www-form-urlencoded-as-the-conte?noredirect=1#comment75105380_44039671). However, in this question I'm specifically wondering about what could cause Sails Skipper to not raise any errors, but have `uploadedFiles` with a length of 0

Comment: My best guess is that it simply means that nothing is actually getting uploaded, so it succeeds, but with no files being returned. But it would be helpful to know if something else could be causing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [skipper github](https://github.com/balderdashy/skipper/blob/master/index.js). It doesn't class an empty content length as an error. It simply skips all the hard body parsing work.

```
if (
  // If we have a content-length header...
  !_.isUndefined(req.headers['content-length']) &&
  // And the content length is declared to be zero...
  (req.headers['content-length'] === 0 || req.headers['content-length'] === '0')) {
  // Then we set the body to any empty object
  // and skip all this body-parsing mishegoss.
  req.body = {};
  return next();
}
```