# Dropzone sending a request with 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' as the content-type

Tags: http-headers, dropzone.js

I'm using dropzone to upload files to my sails backend.

For the longest time, I have been unable to figure out why it isn't working. However, when I put the `req` object in the `console.log`, I got the following headers (i.e., this would be req.headers) :

```
headers:
  { 'x-id': 'vendor-______________',
  'x-token': '_______________',
  host: 'localhost:1337',
  'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'content-length': '0',
  connection: 'close' 
  },
```

I'm guessing this means that dropzone is missing something up, so that it is not sending the request with a `content-type` of `multipart`

Here's the dropzone code itself: (Note that it is closely related to the example given in the dropzone docs, but is part of a react component)

```
Component.add("DropzoneComponent", {
  getDefaultProps: function(){
    return {}
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
      var c = this
      var field = new Dropzone(c.refs.dropzone, {
          url: c.props.url,
          paramName: "csv"
      });
      field.on("error", function(fileObject, err) {
        console.log("dropzone file object:", fileObject, "***Error message***", err);  
      })  
      field.on("success", function(fileObject, file){
          console.log("file object", fileObject, "file:", file);
      })  

  render: function(){
      return (
          <span>
            <input type="hidden" value={this.state.image || ""} name={this.props.name || ""} />
            <div id="upload-field" ref="dropzone" type="file" className="dropzone"></div>
          </span>
      )
  }
```

Any guesses on why would this would be, or if I am misdiagnosing the situation?

Comment: can you show the dropzone code?

Comment: @AgamBanga I can, good idea; just made the edit

Comment: @RyanQuey Are you using the react-dropzone package?

Comment: @Glen Actually, now that you mention it, it is in the projects node-modules folder, but I'm not sure if it's implemented or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was actually due to how we were setting up axios in the end. Something related to [this issue](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/362), and unrelated to DropZone.